# How to Identify the Message Queue name in Spring Jms Message Listener

Tags: jms, spring-jms

How to Identify the originating destination of a message received in Spring JMS Message Listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the way  the message.getJmsDestination () gives the destination from where the destination name can be retrieved

Comment: For example, `((Queue) msg.getJMSDestination()).getQueueName()`